# Convert string format python

Tags: python, beginner, strings, formatting

I want to fix number of digits after '.' in digit represented by string.

Is there better solution than mine?

#### My code

```
def convert(s):
    """ Convert 1234.12345678 to 1234.123"""
    vec = s.split('.')
    if len(vec) == 2 and len(vec[1]) > 3:
        return vec[0] + '.' + vec[1][:3]
    return s
```

Comment: `def convert(s): return f'{float(s):.3f}'`

Comment: @TedBrownlow The answer box is the place for posting answers.  Comments are for requesting clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this would be sufficient:

```
return '{0:1.3f}'.format(s)
```

(provided that the argument passed is a float).
There is no need for a function.

The above will return a **string**, if you want to return a float then use the float function:

```
return float('{0:1.3f}'.format(s))
```

Or even shorter, taking advantage of F-strings. I prefer this option personally:

```
return f'{s:.3f}'
```

Again, this returns a string but you can cast it to a float if necessary.

As a reference: [Python f-string tutorial](http://zetcode.com/python/fstring/)

Comment: The f-string is impressively faster than the string format method. If you are in 3.6+ I would go for that option.

Answer (score 2):

Let's raise the bar a bit here.

## Function Declaration

`def convert(s):`

This function converts ... something.  Inches to feet?  Celsius to Fahrenheit?  The function name doesn't give us any clue.  The function argument `s` is similarly non-descriptive.

What does the function do?  It truncates a string 3 characters after the first period character, if one is present.  We could name the function that:

`def truncate_3_characters_after_period(s):`

A wee bit too verbose, and it doesn't quite match what appears to be the intended usage.  From the doc-string, the function seems to be intended to apply to strings representing floating-point quantities, so maybe:

`def truncate_to_3_decimal_places(s):`

That is better, but no longer implies the function is expecting a string, or returns a string.  Type-hints go a long way here.

`def truncate_to_3_decimal_places(s: str) -> str:`

The type-hints don't actually do anything; they are ignored by the Python interpreter.  They are read by programs like `mypy`, which can use this static type information to spot possible errors in your program.  They are also read and used by some documentation generating programs, which is very useful.

## Doc-string

`""" Convert 1234.12345678 to 1234.123"""`

I love doc-strings.  But this one is a little lacking in detail.  It looks like it says it converts a floating point value to another floating point value with fewer significant digits.  But the function doesn't do that at all; the function expects and returns strings.

`"""Convert '1234.12345678' to '1234.123'"""`

That is slightly clearer.  The astute reader will see the single quotation marks, and realize it is not a numerical transformation, but a textual one.

But, many questions are left unanswered.  Does `'123.4567'` get rounded to `'123.457'`, or truncated to `'123.456'`?

```py
    """
    Truncate the string representation of a float after 3 decimal places.

    >>> convert('1234.12345678')
    '1234.123'

    >>> convert('123.45678')
    '123.456'

    >>> convert('123')
    '123'
    """
```

That is better doc-string.  It describes, in words, what the function is doing, and then goes on to provide three examples, the second showing the truncation, the third showing what happens when the string doesn't have a decimal point.

As a bonus, the format of the examples in the doc-string allow the doc-string to do double duty.  You can run `doctest.testmod()` on the module, and the examples become test-cases, and the output is compared with the documented output, and deviations are flagged.

## Exceptional cases

The function does a few bizarre things.

### `len(vec) == 2`

If and only if the string has 2 parts, will the length of the second part be tested.

```py
>>> convert('192.168.0.1')
'192.168.0.1'
```

Should the function have returned that value?  Would `192.168` be a more expected result?  Perhaps raising a `ValueError` would be even better?

### Exponential Notation

```py
>>> convert(str(1234567890123456.0))
'1.234'

>>> convert(str(0.000000001234))
'1.234'
```

Whoa!  Those results are unexpected!  Clearly, it does not handle the floating point values in exponential representation.

Is this a bug?  Or is this a limitation, which should be spelt out in the docstring?

### Alternate representation

```py
>>> convert("123.4")
'123.4'

>>> convert("123.400321")
'123.400'
```

The returned values would both represent the same floating point values, but their representations are different.  Should the function add zeros to pad to 3 decimal places?  Should this difference be mentioned in the doc-string?

## Quality-of-Life

How is this function used?  Do you already have the string representation of the floating point value, or are you converting the float-point value into a string for passing to the function?

A function which takes a float, and converts it to a string, truncated to the desired precision might make handling special cases easier.

## Internationalization

Some regions do not use the period (`.`) as the decimal indicator.  A comma (`,`) may be used to separate the integral part from the fractional.  For instance, an approximation to pi might appear as `3,14159`.  Since you've hard-coded your function to split the string at the period character, the application would break in France.

Using built-in formatting would take care of internationalization concerns.  For instance, `f"{value:.3f}"` would convert `value` to a fixed-point string with 3 digits after the decimal point, even if the decimal point appears as the comma (`,`) character.  However, it would **round** based on the digit that comes next, instead of **truncating** the value, which does not appear to match what you've written.

You could explicitly truncate the value to the required resolution

```
value = math.trunc(value * 1000) / 1000
```

and then convert the result to a string using `f"{value:.3f}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the format() function to get the result.

```
def convert(s):
    """ Convert 1234.12345678 to 1234.123"""
    s = print("{:.3f}".format(float(s)))
s = "1234.12345678"
convert(s)
```

Refer to this link to know more about [String Formatting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-formatting-in-python/).

Comment: Why do you assign the return value of `print()` to `s`? And why do you print in `convert()` at all instead of just returning the formatted str?